# Design for container that holds multiple instances of same base class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have four different classes. First being a base class for the second and third. The fourth being a container class that holds instances of second and third (stored as first).

My base class for `PC` and `Companion`

```
public class Controllable
{
    protected String name;
    protected int x;

    public Controllable (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void move () {
        x++;
    }
}

public class PC extends Controllable
{
    private int someUniqueVariable;

    public PC (String name, int someUniqueVariable) {
        super (name);
        this.someUniqueVariable = someUniqueVariable;
    }
}

public class Companion extends Controllable
{
    public Companion (String name) {
        super (name);
    }
}
```

And finally the wrapper/container class.

```
public class Party
{
    private PC pc;
    private List<Controllable> members;

    public Party () {
        PC = new PC ("PC", 1); // edit #1: should be pc, bad copy-paste
        members = new ArrayList<Controllable>();
        members.add (PC);
        members.add (new Companion ("Companion1");
        members.add (new Companion ("Companion2");
    }

    public moveAll () {
        for (Controllable m : members) {
            m.move();
        }
    }

    public getPC () {
        return pc;
    }
}
```

Now if I want to move all `Controllable` I will iterate over `members`. If there are `pc`  specifics I will simply call the PC and use its move function. `PC` will be more separated from `Companion` later on.

I would mostly like feedback on the design of my code.

**Edit #1:**

The most critical area were I want feedback is this. Most things are shared between `Companion` and `PC`, however there are some unique features of `PC`. In 99% I want to be able to iterate over all of the party members In more rare cases I want to only access the `Companion`s and sometimes I only want to access the PC.

```
public Party () {
    pc = new PC ("PC", 1);
    members = new ArrayList<>();
    members.add (PC);
    members.add (new Companion ("Companion1");
    members.add (new Companion ("Companion2");
}
```

*Minor edit to show an error in the code.*

Comment: Looks good, however, would it be possible to make an array of Companions a property of PC? That is only assuming that the Companions will always follow the PC.

Comment: @CBredlow, Companions will always follow the PC, but not vice-verse. So possible yes, however doesn't that break the design a bit? Trying to move those parts to `Party`.

Comment: I don't think it would, but it was just a thought. It may add more work so it might not be a good idea to do my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`Controllable` class

- can be `abstract`, it doesn't seem you will instantiate it
- `int x` field shall be private, you don't use it anywhere

`Party` class

- you declared variable of type `PC` with lower letters so object assignment shall be too `pc = new PC ("PC", 1);`
- `members = new ArrayList<Controllable>();` with Java 8 it is not necessary to declare list's type if you do this with variable declaration, so `members = new ArrayList<>();` is enough

It is a good practice to make method arguments `final`, as well class fields if they are provided through constructor. It means their declared type cannot be changed.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Code Review. Good spotting for the `PC` -> `pc` bug. That's what happens when people try to 'edit' or 'fix' their code before posting to Code Review.... it leads to unexpected bugs. The [Diamond operator `<>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond) is available in Java7 too, FYI.

Comment: The ´abstract´ part makes sense. The `int x` is just a temporary variable. The `PC = new PC ("PC", 1);` is a typo. Basically everything is temporary in this code apart from the storing. I should emphasize that a bit more I guess.

Comment: @Leszek, I have never ever seen `final` in method arguments. Do you have perhaps have some good examples of where I can read more about that?

Comment: Lots of resources: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=23 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154314/when-should-one-use-final-for-method-parameters-and-local-variables , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137868/using-final-modifier-whenever-applicable-in-java , http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/48413/in-java-should-i-use-final-for-parameters-and-locals-even-when-i-dont-have-t